# Paypal Payflow Link ASP.Net MVC Open Source Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, payflowpro

I am looking at creating a site using ASP.Net MVC which of coarse has a paid membership option and needs to allow recuring payments via Paypal.  I am thinking of using Paypals Payflow Link as the site will be fairly small.  I am looking for an Open Source example or Framework that I can use with Payflow Link.  Are there any good .Net Frameworks that only handle the payment system.  The rest of the app will be custom app.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about Payflow Link then you do not do the payment system. It is hosted by Paypal, the  user gets sent to Paypal and then back when payment is complete.

If you are referring to PayFlow Pro then the following link goes to the Paypal Payflowpro technical document ion. https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_gateway_payflowpro

PayflowPro payment system is very easy, basically construct a SOAP request and handle a response. The documentation is very easy.

As for integrating into MVC, if you are doing the front end custom, then the back end is mostly just API integration.